# How do you create an enumerator wrapper class?

Tags: ruby

I have this function:

```
def file_parser (filename)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    File.open(filename, "r:ISO-8859-1") do |file|
      csv = CSV.new(file, :col_sep => "\t", :headers => true, :quote_char => "\x07")                            
      csv.each do |row|
        yielder.yield map_fields(clean_data(row.to_hash))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I can use it like this:

```
parser = file_parser("data.tab")
parser.each do { |data| do_profitable_things_with data }
```

Instead, I'd like to put it in its own class and use it like this:

```
parser = SpecialParser.new("data.tab")
parser.each do { |data| do_profitable_things_with data }
```

I've tried some things I didn't expect to work, like just returning the enumerator out of `initialize()`, and `self = file_parser()`.

I've also tried `super do |yielder|`.

For some reason, the way to do this is not coming to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just include the `Enumerable` module into your class, and define an `each` function which calls `yield`.

You still get all the `Enumerable` methods like `map`, `reduce`, etc, for free.

```
class SpecialParser
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(n)
    @n = n
  end

  def each
    0.upto(@n) { |i| yield i }
  end
end

sp = SpecialParser.new 4
sp.each { |i| p i }
p sp.map { |i| i }
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `file_parser` a private method in `SpecialParser`.

Then set up the rest of the class like this:

```
class SpecialParser
  include Enumerable  # needed to provide the other Enumerable methods

  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename
    @enum = file_parser(filename)
  end

  def each
    @enum.each do |val|
      yield val
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:

If you want the other Enumerable method for free, you also have to `include Enumerable` in the class.

Comment: Then what happens when somebody wants to do `each_with_index` or `next` or some other method they'd expect from an enumerator? I'd have to define every method.

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff Ok, edited. I was a bit confused because you only suggested it should act like an `Enumerable` in the title. Without reading that, I thought you only wanted the `each` method.